# Google Fit Data without user logged in

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I work for a company that develops health care web applications for the health system. I'm wondering if there is a way to allow a user to preauthorize a website to pull data on their behalf. This would allow a physician to view a patient's data from Google Fit once the patient has authorized it without that Google Account being logged into the web browser in question after preauthorization.